# SQL Help: SELECT CASE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for some general guidance on the best solution for a reoccurring SQL query.  Basically, I want to create a view of a table which has a lot of nearly identical rows, (except for 1 discerning column called [Status], which can be either 'Closed' or 'Draft').

I want to return distinct data for each [Port], if both 'Closed' and 'Draft' exist, then return only the 'Draft' row data, and if only 'Closed' exists, then return the 'Closed' row data.

Please refer to the attached files for a visual. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!  I believe this solution will lend itself well to other practical cases/solutions for me in the future - thank you!

Original Table Data:

[image: Original Table Data]

Example Output:

[image: Example Output]

Comment: What have you tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
select c.Port,c.DateAdded,max(Status) as Status
from myTable c
group by  c.Port,c.DateAdded
```

Basically, group the table, and take the highest status code (Closed or Draft)
If both exists, **Draft** will be returned

Answer (score 1):

A rewording of your requirement is to return just one row per Port, and that Draft rows take precidence over Closed rows.

You don't make clear if they can have different dates though. Such that if one port has two Draft rows or two Closed rows, do you want the earlier dated row, or the later dated row?

The code below presumes the dates can indeed be different, and that your prefer the later dated row.

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY port ORDER BY status DESC, dateAdded DESC) AS seq_num
  FROM
    YourTable
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
  seq_num = 1
```

If the dates are always identical, `MAX(status)` with `GROUP BY port, dateAdded` is easily sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.Status = 'Draft'
   OR NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM tablename t2 
            WHERE t2.Port = t1.Port AND t1.Status = 'Draft'
          )
```

Or with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT Port, DateAdded, Status
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Port ORDER BY CASE WHEN Status = 'Draft' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) rn
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a full outer join, and coalesce the results so that the "draft" row is preferred over the "closed" row:

```sql
SELECT          COALESCE(d.Port, c.Port),
                COALESCE(d.DateAdded, c.DateAdded),
                COALESCE(d.Status, c.Status)
FROM            (SELECT Port, DateAdded, Status
                 FROM   mytable
                 WHERE  Status = 'Draft') d
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT Port, DateAdded, Status
                 FROM   mytable
                 WHERE  Status = 'Closed') c ON d.Port = c.Port
```